# how can i increase the core quota limit on microsoft.HDInsight azure?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

i created a free azure account and wanted to create a spark cluster using  **microsoft.HDInsight**
everything worked perfectly until i reached **configuration + price** step.
i got this message. -on this screen shot-

[image]

"You have reached the core quota limit of your subscription in France Central. Choose another region or ask billing support to increase your limit for France Central".

i have tried changing to multiple regions but i always get the exact same message.

how can i solve that ?

***i would highely appriciate any help :)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Portal > Click on Help + support icon > create a support request:

[image]

Select your required service like **HDInsight** for which you want to increase the quota and **Issue type** is service and subscription limits (quotas)

[image]

Fill the details and submit, they will contact you over email or phone in their business working hours regarding the location and case status.

**Note**: ***Free Trial subscriptions aren't eligible for limit or quota increases. If you have a Free Trial subscription, you can upgrade to a Pay-As-You-Go subscription***.

**Here is the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits) that shows the Services and Subscriptions Quota Limits of Azure**.

Comment: your answer normaly works but using a payed subscription not the free one, but it helped me find the answer . i poster another answer to my own question down bellow. thanks for ur help :)

Comment: Yes @abcosmoweb, here is the [MSFT Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits) shows you min and max quota limits of Azure subscription.

Comment: yes , but the thing is you can not choose 0 quota the least value is 1. and it's impossible to modify the ones above . *so it becomes impossible to increase it using a free subscription*

Comment: Yes, we didn't have that quota request facility in free subscription. I have updated my answer and normally this is the main process to quota request for Pay-As-You-Go Subscriptions!

Answer (score 2):

So i have found that it is quiet impossible to request to increase  the core quota using the free subscription, following the steps of the answer that @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT showed, i ended up geting that message.

"**Your free trial subscription is not eligible for a quota increase. To request a quota increase, first upgrade to a pay-as-you-go subscription**"

[image]